# cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIAlertController' with an argument list type '(title:string, message:

Tags: swift, xcode7, swift2

I am getting this error after updating to Swift2 not sure what I am missing. Here is my code: error happens on anything that has var alert = UIAlertController and any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
 // Validate the text fields
    if username!.characters.count < 5 {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater than 5 characters", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else if password!.characters.count < 8 {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Password must be greater than 8 characters", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else if email!.characters.count < 8 {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid", message: "Please enter a valid email address", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else {
        // Run a spinner to show a task in progress
        var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        spinner.startAnimating()

        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = username
        newUser.password = password
        newUser.email = finalEmail

        // Sign up the user asynchronously
        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            // Stop the spinner
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            if ((error) != nil) {
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Signed Up", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") 
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use all those tags. It is either related to xcode or the language, rarely both. It is also just about one version of the language not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialiser for `UIAlertController` looks like this :

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```

The `UIAlertController` is presented like this :

```
viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
    //something when the alert has been clicked
})
```

Optionals are unwrapped like this :

```
guard let unWrappedUserName = username else {
    return
}

if unWrappedUserName.characters.count < 5 {
```

You might want to add actions to the Alert like this :

```
var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Alert Option 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // some stuff when they cancel
})

var stuffAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Alert Option 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    // some other stuff
})

myAlertController.addAction(cancelAction)
myAlertController.addAction(stuffAction)
```

Comment: I see what they did there. Thanks Menke

Comment: @Birdman3000 updated with the answer to the question you were going to ask in 10 minutes. Don't forget to upvote and welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIAlertViewController` as designed with a custom `UIAlertAction`

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Signed Up", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { action in
        //Do whatever you want
}
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find pretty neat example in Swift 2 Blueprints by Cecil Costa, inside subchapter: Creating helpers

```
extension UIViewController {
    func displayError(message:String){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel) { _ in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```